# complex orderby that links to another table

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

I have the following query to start with:

```
var query = from p in db.Products
                        from pc in p.NpProductCategories
                        where pc.CategoryId == categoryId 
                        select p;
```

I'm applying some more filtering on it and in the end I want to sort the results:

```
if (orderBy == ProductSortingEnum.Name)
                    query = query.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
                else
                    query = query.OrderBy(............);
```

My big problem (coming from not knowing linq too good) is the ELSE here. How can I sort results by a column that is not in the current result set? I would like to somehow link to another linq query in the orderby. **The sorting I'm trying to achive is to link to NpProductVariants query using the ProductId to match between NpProductVariant and Products
 and sort by the Price of the NpProductVariant**

Comment: Please use *cursive* text instead of BOLD when you highligh more than a few words :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you have the relationship set up in the dbml...

For one to one (and many to one):

```
query = query.OrderBy(p => p.NpProductVariant.Price);
```

For one to many:

```
query = query.OrderBy(p => p.NpProductVariants.Select(v => v.Price).Max());
```

---

Also:

```
var query =
  from p in db.Products 
  where p.NpProductCategories.Any(pc => pc.CategoryId == categoryId)
  select p;
```

Comment: you are a genius!!! It's the second variants you gave that I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can hook your `Join` to your query as long as it is returning the same thing. So maybe something like (I'm not 100 % sure since I haven't tried it):

```
            query = from i1 in query
                 join i2 in query2 on i1.PropertyToJoin equals i2.PropertyToJoin
                 orderby i1.OrderProp1, i2.OrderProp2
                 select i1;
```

But I think it might be a good idea to check the generated sql so it is still effective.

Comment: the problem is that a little later in the code I do paging: query.Skip(index * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList(), which requires a sorted enumeration. If I do it in the query like that I get an exception: The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'.

Comment: Why is that a problem? Let us back track, does it work if you only have the first `order by`? If so, it should work for the second one as long as the the resulting query has the same return type.